# Not able to open PDF url using DocumentViewer ionic 4

Tags: pdf, ionic-framework, ionic4

I have a pdf URL and I want to open it using `DocumentViewer`. When I run code:

```
this._document.viewDocument(pdfUrl, 'application/pdf', options);
```

It is not opening PDF. I tried downloading PDF to my mobile and then open it. Please find code below:

```
transfer.download(downloadUrl, filename).then(entry => {
      const url = entry.toURL();
      if (this._plt.is('ios')) {
        this._document.viewDocument(pdfUrl, 'application/pdf', options);
      } else {
        this._fileOpener.open(pdfUrl, 'application/pdf')
          .then(() => console.log('File is opened'))
          .catch(e => this.presentAlert('Error opening file', e));
      }
    });
```

I have tables and images in my PDF. When I ran above code I am not able to see HTML5 tables in the PDF.

I need help on how to open up PDF URL directly using `DocumentViewer`.

**NOTE:** I have seen a couple of post on StackOverflow suggesting to use `InAppBrowser`. I have a requirement where I need to display it as PDF.

Comment: did you find any proper solution to view pdf in IONIC?

Answer (score 0):

I have read in https://github.com/sitewaerts/cordova-plugin-document-viewer,

that in android : Due to license restrictions in muPDF, the plugin dispatches to a separate (free) viewer app based on muPDF. If the viewer app is not yet installed, the user may be redirected to the google play app store.

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=de.sitewaerts.cleverdox.viewer.

you may use other pdf plugins like

https://github.com/vadimdez/ng2-pdf-viewer/

hope this helps